# JDBC step -> Can I run SQL query in transaction?

Tags: jdbc, db2, soapui, db2-luw

I am using SOAPUI to run JDBC step on DB2.

I want to run query in transaction but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I tried setting `autoCommit` to `false` in the connection string like this:

```
jdbc:db2://host:50000/DB:user=aostest;password=123;**autoCommit=false**;
```

Query used in JDBC step:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID = 1;

    DELETE FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ID = 2;
END
```

This deletes first row even if second delete statement fails.

I tried executing sql using `EXCEPTION` but got invalid syntax error.

Query:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID = 1;

    DELETE FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ID = 2;

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            ROLLBACK;
END
```

Comment: May be you want to run stored procedure.

Comment: I don't have permissions to create stored procedure

Comment: No you seemed to be running a script from SoapUI. There chose.

Comment: I can choose stored procedure but there is no procedure to call. 

I want to  use this step as teardown for some test.